# D3 pie chart legends with horizontal pagination

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, pagination, legend, pie-chart

I have a requirement where i need to show pagination for legends if the number of legends is more than two. I am using d3 pie chart. Any help would be appreciated.
I have found out something similar but unable to implement using d3 version 5.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your requirement isn't very precise, so it's hard for anyone to help you. Usually you can convert v3 code to v5 without major grief.

Comment: I have a pie chart with n number of legends and its not possible to show all of them at once, for which i need a pagination and at a time to display only 3 or 4. Can you share a example here @Mikkel if possible. Below is the example and its in version 3 also legends are displayed vertically http://bl.ocks.org/pragyandas/6af4113bdb9127260ce1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code you gave in this bl.ocks [link](http://bl.ocks.org/pragyandas/6af4113bdb9127260ce1).

Here is a link of the codepen I created [link](https://codepen.io/peeyush-pant/pen/vYBdOrw).

The pagination implemented here could be directly used with d3 v5. The problem was coming up with the chart.

```
var legendCount = dataSet.series.length;

var legendWidth = 10;
var legendSpacing = 6;

var netLegendHeight = (legendWidth + legendSpacing) * legendCount;
var legendPerPage, totalPages, pageNo;

// if (netLegendHeight / height > 1) {

legendPerPage = 2;
totalPages = Math.ceil(legendCount / legendPerPage);

pageNo = 1;

var startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * legendPerPage;
var endIndex = startIndex + legendPerPage;
var seriesSubset = [],
    colorSubset = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.series.length; i++) {
    if (i >= startIndex && i < endIndex) {
        seriesSubset.push(dataSet.series[i]);
        colorSubset.push(colors[i]);
    }
}

DrawLegendSubset(seriesSubset, colorSubset, legendPerPage, pageNo, totalPages);
// }

function DrawLegendSubset(seriesSubset, colorSubset, legendPerPage, pageNo, totalPages) {

    var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legendg")
        .data(seriesSubset)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr('class', 'legendg')
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (width - 40) + "," + i * (legendWidth + legendSpacing) + ")";
        });

    legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 45)
        .attr("width", legendWidth)
        .attr("height", legendWidth)
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style('fill', function(d, i) {
            return colorSubset[i];
        });


    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 60)
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });


    var pageText = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'pageNo')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 7.5) + "," + (legendPerPage + 1) * (legendWidth + legendSpacing) + ")");

    pageText.append('text').text(pageNo + '/' + totalPages)
        .attr('dx', '.25em');

    var prevtriangle = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'prev')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 5) + "," + (legendPerPage + 1.5) * (legendWidth + legendSpacing) + ")")
        .on('click', prevLegend)
        .style('cursor', 'pointer');

    var nexttriangle = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'next')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 20) + "," + (legendPerPage + 1.5) * (legendWidth + legendSpacing) + ")")
        .on('click', nextLegend)
        .style('cursor', 'pointer');

    nexttriangle.append('polygon')
        .style('stroke', '#000')
        .style('fill', '#000')
        .attr('points', '0,0, 10,0, 5,5');

    prevtriangle.append('polygon')
        .style('stroke', '#000')
        .style('fill', '#000')
        .attr('points', '0,5, 10,5, 5,0');

    if (pageNo == totalPages) {
        nexttriangle.style('opacity', '0.5')
        nexttriangle.on('click', '')
            .style('cursor', '');
    } else if (pageNo == 1) {
        prevtriangle.style('opacity', '0.5')
        prevtriangle.on('click', '')
            .style('cursor', '');
    }

}

function prevLegend() {
    pageNo--;

    svg.selectAll("g.legendg").remove();
    svg.select('.pageNo').remove();
    svg.select('.prev').remove();
    svg.select('.next').remove();

    var startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * legendPerPage;
    var endIndex = startIndex + legendPerPage;

    var seriesSubset = [],
        colorSubset = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.series.length; i++) {
        if (i >= startIndex && i < endIndex) {
            seriesSubset.push(dataSet.series[i]);
            colorSubset.push(colors[i]);
        }
    }

    DrawLegendSubset(seriesSubset, colorSubset, legendPerPage, pageNo, totalPages);
}

function nextLegend() {
    pageNo++;

    svg.selectAll("g.legendg").remove();
    svg.select('.pageNo').remove();
    svg.select('.prev').remove();
    svg.select('.next').remove();

    var startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * legendPerPage;
    var endIndex = startIndex + legendPerPage;

    var seriesSubset = [],
        colorSubset = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.series.length; i++) {
        if (i >= startIndex && i < endIndex) {
            seriesSubset.push(dataSet.series[i]);
            colorSubset.push(colors[i]);
        }
    }

    DrawLegendSubset(seriesSubset, colorSubset, legendPerPage, pageNo, totalPages);
}
```

Here is an image of the final pie chart with pagination:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lone Ranger for the quick reply. I will use this now.

Comment: Welcome, it would be great if you could accept the answer.

Comment: done. Haven't implemented yet but need something similar. Will add comments if need something more. Thanks again @Lone.